# How do I make permanent changes to javascript variables or html elements inside of .click()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scope

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        $('#rightAd').text("HELLO EVERYBODY");
    });
});
```

This only changes the text in #rightAd for the moment the button is clicked.  How do I make it remain, "HELLO EVERYBODY" after the click ends?  Or am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: Remain in the sense, you need "HELLO EVERYBODY" even after page refresh ?

Comment: No, just after the click ends.  As of right now, it just flashes, then disappears.

Comment: are you using `<input type="submit"/>` ?

Comment: yes I am.  Should I be using <button> instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

changing via script will reflect until the page gets refreshed.

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="rightAd"> some text.....</div>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

**JQuery:**

```
    $('#submit').click(function(){
    $('#rightAd').text("HELLO EVERYBODY");
});
```

If you are using `<input type="submit"/>` this will submit your page, so changes will be flashed as page gets refresh.

Use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent form from submission